# Codewars: Alphabet symmetry

Tags: javascript

Nearly i tried to finish a Codewars task called "Alphabet symmetry".
Here is the link: https://www.codewars.com/kata/59d9ff9f7905dfeed50000b0/train/javascript 
I tried finish it on JavaScript language. 
So my code is working and it passes all the tests, except one:

```
Test.assertDeepEquals(solve(["IAMDEFANDJKL","thedefgh","xyzDEFghijabc"]),[6, 3, 7]);
```

The error: Expected: [6, 5, 7], instead got: [6, 3, 7]
My code:

```
function solve(arr){  


let alphabeth = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
  let upAlph = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')
  let result = arr.map(function(elem,index,arr){
    let elArr = elem.split('');
    let sum = 0;
    for(let el of elArr){
      if( (el == alphabeth[elArr.indexOf(el)]) || (el == upAlph[elArr.indexOf(el)])) sum++
    };
    return sum;
  })
  return result;
};
```

Please, help me find the problem
Thank ya;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a logic one:

```
el == alphabeth[elArr.indexOf(el)])
```

Instead of looking through indexes directly, you are doing it *indirectly*, by looking up the index of the element.  The input `thedefgh` contains the letters `e` & `h` twice and is messing with your results.

Try doing it by index in the first place, like so:

```
function solve(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(input) {
        let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
        let arr = input.toLowerCase().split('');
        let sum = 0;
        // You can iterate an array with a forEach AND keep the index:
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
        arr.forEach(function(val, i) {
            // Now the check is much simpler.  See if the character in index I
            // matches the character in the alphabet at index i
            if(val === alphabet[i])
                sum++
        });
        return sum;
    });
}
```